# HTML email template outlook rendering issue

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

My HTML-Email template is not rendering properly in Outlook.

Gmail:

[image]

Outlook desktop:

[image]

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 90%;border-collapse: collapse;align-content: center;">
  <tr>
    <td style=" background-color: #ececec; display: block;border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;padding: 5px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;"></td>
    <td id="title" style="background-color: #ececec; display: table-cell;width: 40%; padding: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;">SHOP WITH CONFIDENCE</td>
    <td style=" background-color: #ececec; display: block;border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;padding: 5px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to make it same looking as in Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 2-row table layout. Unfortunately `rowspan` does not work well in Outlook. You still can include a suitable inside the table cells. Then you should remove most of your styling from the table cells. It makes no sense to use `display: block` on those cells and then redeclares `display: tabel-cell` on them later on. Just use the default straight away.

Last but not least, you have to use `&nbsp` to add content to the table cells as they would collapse otherwise.

I also moved the `background-color` from the cells to the table itself.

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 90%;border-collapse: collapse;align-content: center; background-color: #ececec;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td id="title" style="width: 40%; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;">SHOP WITH CONFIDENCE</td>
    <td>
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but it is still not looking good in outlook here is screenshot of outlook https://i.imgur.com/ff2RiyB.png

Comment: @ishaq try with the edited code, please. I missed that Outlook has issues with `rowspan`.